# Using pictures of kidnapped kid and pretending to be them?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture

I saw [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391249/tiny) today. Wow I thought. Such a young kid and so accomplished already. I felt bad. But hey, it seems to be a joke. Let's search for his profile picture on Google! Oh..
[**British youngster snatched off the street in Malaysia**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2136270/British-youngster-snatched-street-Malaysia-walked-school.html)

I'm not saying it's the worst thing ever worth any severe punishment for, just that it might be slightly distasteful to use THIS picture.

Comment: @Xyzk - Great job finding that out. I would have never thought of searching for the profile picture of a small boy in Google. Something needs to be done about this(I know we can have the profile pic of anybody, but this doesn't seem good).

Comment: This is really bad. Good you brought this up. Rather than *slightly untasteful* i find it **severely untasteful** Hopefully the mods can do something about this.

Comment: Okay, so the picture's _probably_ in very bad taste but you did just make me click on a link to the Daily Mail so I'm now dirty as well.

Comment: I still feel bad, though, because I am reminded there are genuine 13 year old kids that have even higher-voted stack overflow ques.. uh, I mean, are *even smarter* than that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber he just made up some real sad story about himself that is not only too unbelievable to be true but also contradicts everything in the daily mail article. Some people really stop at nothing to just get a few points extra. Maybe the poor kid isn't even alive anymore

Comment: @Michael, searching for the name I found [this](http://www.ibtimes.com/kidnapped-boy-nayati-moodliar-found-alive-malaysia-ransom-paid-family-safe-return-695729) article, so he was found alive a few days later.

Comment: @stema at least thankfully he's alive and well. I really feared he got taken and killed by some pervert

Comment: We had [a similar user-account "problem"](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5764), which was solved by the user updating their profile. I doubt there is much that can be done except for the user themselves... I've [posted a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java#comment28788233_19418427) to the user's most recent question as an invitation to weigh in on this situation.

Comment: There is always a chance this is actually that boy - or it's an ordinary adult programmer, maybe even 70 or 80 years old, who just want some love and attention. Judging from his style of writing and skills, I'd take a wild guess it's the later. Either way nothing here is illegal or offensive in any way, just let it be.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd identity theft is [definitely illegal](http://www.lawstuff.org.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/14885/IndentityTheft-fact-sheet.pdf)

Comment: @Michael that user never made any official claim he's that boy - until then, it's no different than [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) who might be charged for stealing the identity of Liam Neeson, according to your logic. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I agree with you, he seems to be an older person. checking this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/87887/revisions) stats that he is using proper way of capitalization which only an educated/mature person/user can do. Not a kid of 13 years.

Comment: @Vigbyor My age is around 13 and my capitalization skills are better than many adults. Please don't generalize. Though "which only an educated/mature person/user can do" is mostly correct.

Comment: @Vigbyor I was contributing to Wikipedia with proper capitalization and grammar since I was 11. Also, from what I've seen on the Internet, frequency of bad capitalization/grammar is the same for both kids and adults.

Comment: The self-description in this user's profile is wildly different from the description of the boy given in the various news stories. I think it's very unlikely that this is the same person.

Comment: Follow through time and you can see his bio get progressively more pitiful http://web.archive.org/web/20120722224456/http://stackoverflow.com/users/1391249/tiny. Screams rep grab

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have reverted the profile image to be an identicon and sent a message to the user about the inappropriateness of using that particular image.

Comment: Only on his SO account, it seems. At least Meta, SU and CR profiles still have the picture.

Comment: @AndersUP - Probably SE employee or Community manager will(can) update it globally.

Comment: @AndersUP - I only have the ability change pictures where I have a diamond. I forgot to check his MSO profile and I'll go and change that now. In the meantime can you either raise a question on Meta SU **and** Meta CR or flag one his posts on those sites for their mods to do the same.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know you didn't have access on those. Just mentioned it in case you forgot.

Comment: The propagation of the identicon to replace the questionable image is now `status-completed`. @ChrisF thanks for taking care of this so quickly.

Comment: @Tim [you missed a spot](http://stackexchange.com/users/1482116/tiny).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - as far as I can remember the SE profile is auto updated from the users oldest profile on a hourly(?) basis. So if the oldest profile has only just been changed it might take a while to filter through. Though it does look like SO is his oldest profile.

Comment: @ChrisF checked my own network profile and it says: *Sync with oldest profile (Stack Overflow). Last sync 0s ago* - so maybe it's synched only when the user himself visits his own network profile? In this case, hope dev team member has a way to force it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I forced a sync, all good.

Comment: @Tim nice powers you got there in your sleeve! ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That particular power resides in my toe. Well one toe on each foot, for redundancy and all.

Comment: @Tim omg... scared to even imagine what powers reside in your little finger!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This could be leading to the worst 'pull my finger' joke _ever_ to come out of meta. I'm pretty sure it would be the first, too, but definitely the _worst_.

Comment: @Tim hmm... this can be super uber ultra effective weapon against trolls, spammers, and sock puppet masters! :P